# are two the following functors isomorphic

Tags: category-theory, natural-transformations

Consider the following two functors that go $C^{op}\times C\to Set$, where $X$ is an object in $C$

1. $(A,B)\mapsto Set(C(X,A)\times A,B)$
2. $(A,B)\mapsto Set(C(X,A),Set(A,B))$

Are these two functors isomorphic? (i.e. is there an natural transformation between them that is an isomorphism?)
I want to think that they are due to $Set(A\times B,C)\cong Set(A,Set(B,C))$, but I haven't grasped all the details.

Comment: These assignments aren't well-formed. For one, $X$ is undefined. For another, you can't take the product of an object of $\mathbf C$ with a set: $\mathbf C(X, A) \times A$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: @varkor: actually there is a very natural way to make sense of $c \times X$ where $c$ is an object of a category and $X$ is a set; it's (if it exists) the coproduct of $X$ copies of $c$. This fits into an adjunction $\text{Hom}(c \times X, d) \cong \text{Hom}(X, \text{Hom}(c, d))$ (again, if it exists). This operation is sometimes called "copowering": https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/copower

Comment: @Merk: I don't understand the types of the objects involved here from what you've written. Are $A, B$ supposed to be objects of a category $C$? If so what does $\text{Set}(A, B)$ mean?

Comment: that's right, I think I've screwed up the types, maybe it should be $Set(C(X,A)\times FA,GB)$ and $Set(C(X,A),Set(FA,GB))$ respectively, where $F,G$ are functors $C\to Set$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in the end the two functors are isomorphic, but you need some care in specifying in what sense $Set(X,Y)\times Z$ is an object of $\cal C$ for every $Z$ (instead of $Set(C(X,A)\times A,B)$, you want to write ${\cal C(\cal C}(X,A)\times A,B)$, or the only way to make $Set(C(X,A)\times A,B)$ type-check is to impose ${\cal C} = Set$).

The correct statement involves [tensors](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/copower) over the category of sets.

Now, the adjunction given by the fact that $\cal C$ is tensored
$$
{\cal C}({\cal C}(X,A)\times A,B)\cong Set({\cal C}(X,A), {\cal C}(A,B))
$$
is a *natural* isomorphism in all arguments, and the claim follows.

Answer (score 0):

If we have a fixed functor $U:C\to Set$ (typically the 'underlying set' functor)  and a fixed object $X\in C$, then the cited natural isomorphism only implies
$$Set(C(X,A)\times UA,\, UB)\ \cong\ Set(C(X,A),\, Set(UA,UB))\,.$$
In case $U$ admits a *left adjoint* $F$, we get that $Set(UA,UB)$ is further naturally isomorphic to $C(FUA,\, B)$, and by the way, if the *unit* $1_C\to FU$ of this adjunction is invertible (which is rarely the case, at least in categories of algebraic structures), *then* it will also be naturally isomorphic to $C(A,B)$.